# Automating PGP encryption? (Windows)

Tags: windows, pgp

Let's say I have daily files that need to be encrypted using PGP (and then emailed) and I want to automate this task. I would be using Windows PowerShell to manipulate the files (examine date/times etc), but how can I automate the PGP part?

I am using the PGP software manually, but I do not see any command line options. I do see a command line software from the same place (Symantec) but for $3000 which I can't do.

I found GnuPG, but (according to GnuPG's FAQ) PGP cannot decrypt GnuPG files if using v 2.x or if using v 5.x then PGP has to use more options. The receiving users are not be willing to make things more complex with extra options required.

In short, I am looking for a command line PGP for Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The incompatibility is only for v2.x of PGP.  For v5.x, the GPG (not PGP as you state) needs to have [more options](http://www.gnupg.org/faq/GnuPG-FAQ.html#how-can-i-encrypt-a-message-so-that-pgp-is-able-to-decrypt-it).

If the problem with PGP 2.x is truly an issue, then you will probably have to shell out for the PGP command-line version.  Note that [PGP v5 appears to have been released in 1997](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#PGP_3_and_founding_of_PGP_Inc.) and PGP v2 was in 1992-ish, so unless you are dealing with recipients that do not upgrade, you will probably have good coverage.

## Import your key and others:

`gpg -v --import c:\pgp\my-pub-and-priv-pgp-key.asc`

## Import each recipient key

`gpg -v --import c:\pgp\pub\recipient1.asc

...

gpg -v --import c:\pgp\pub\recipientN.asc`

For some reason the command-line options are really hard to find in the locally installed Windows manual; [here they are](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Configuration-Options.html).

Now use --batch for batch mode, --passphrase-file to have your private key unlocking phrase read from the given file instead of from the keyboard via the gpg-agent*, and always trust the recipient keys.  If you don't need to have the output signed, then obviously you won't need to use or unlock your private key.

## Encrypt (-e) and sign (-s) a file

`gpg -v --always-trust --batch --passphrase-file mypassphrasefile -se -r
 recipient1 -r recipient2 ... -r recipientN -o output-file file-to-encrypt`

Files **should** be able to be decrypted and verified with PGP by the recipients.

*I don't think I have to say what kind of potentially bad idea it is to store your private key passphrase in a cleartext file.  Note that on Windows, the gpg-agent will read your private key from the keyboard and cache it.  The time period it caches it for can be set in the gpg-agent.conf file, though I've not tried this ([see here for some potential pointers](http://ygingras.net/b/2009/3/longer-passphrase-cache-for-gpg); the gpg-agent.conf resides in your home dir which is set using the GNUPGHOME env var or by setting the HKCU\Software\GNU\GnuPG:HomeDir string variable).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use GPG on your side and use the self-decrypting archive option. You would need to use GPG on a Windows box on your side and you would just need to attach a password. Might have to play with it for a while as I have not done it in a number of years.

Comment: A PGP key is required (and is used by the current method with PGP software) by the receiving users. I can't add anything on like a password; or is there a way to handle it the same way?

Comment: Self-decrypting archives are a bad security practice (they train people to run `.exe` files they got in their email, or whereever) and should be obliterated.